# Can I reuse inline/hardcoded type from component.d.ts file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to selectively pass props to the library component.

Library has created an inline type by hardcoding multiple values.

I interest of my code upgrading automatically with additions to the library defined type can I reuse those inline values without recreating them

Inside library --> component.d.ts file has

```
export interface TooltipProps {
  ...manyOtherProps,
  placement?: | 'bottom-end' | 'bottom-start' | 'bottom' | 'left-end' | 'left-start' | 'left' | 'right-end' | 'right-start' | 'right' | 'top-end' | 'top-start' | 'top';
}
```

I tried some attempts with keyof and valueof

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type PlacementStrings = ValueOf<TooltipProps>
interface JustPlacement { 
  placement: "top"
}

type PlacementStringsKeys = keyof TooltipProps & keyof JustPlacement

type stpls = ValueOf<PlacementStringsKeys>
```

But not getting the needed thing.

which would be **without rewriting it**

```
interface CustomTooltipProps {
  placement?: | 'bottom-end' | 'bottom-start' | 'bottom' | 'left-end' | 'left-start' | 'left' | 'right-end' | 'right-start' | 'right' | 'top-end' | 'top-start' | 'top';
}
```

Comment: Did you try extracting the type ? `let x : TooltipProps['placement'];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Pick` helper to create a new object type including all keys/values where the key is assignable to the specified type:

```
// mylib.ts
export interface TooltipProps {
  foo: "bar";
  placement?: | 'bottom-end' | 'bottom-start' | 'bottom' | 'left-end' | 'left-start' | 'left' | 'right-end' | 'right-start' | 'right' | 'top-end' | 'top-start' | 'top';
}

// otherfile.ts
import type { TooltipProps } from "./mylib";

type CustomTooltipProps = Pick<TooltipProps, "placement">;

// this is expanded into the following:
type CustomTooltipProps = {
    placement?: "bottom-end" | "bottom-start" | "bottom" | "left-end" | "left-start" | "left" | "right-end" | "right-start" | "right" | "top-end" | "top-start" | "top" | undefined;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgFQggBsYEwAFKCMAZzgG8BYAKDjnSIC44AiAI0xReAblbswxHMAC2wFAH4eAHzgByfhBgwIMgLTyAJmriqNWnftowhME2c3bd99cWDoYBpMdOv3n61sXNTcPYKgEAHMAC08jcKjYvUDYBJi7XzUdMC8fM2zkm1TM7LUxFgBfVlYYAE8wPABhAFdrXUISMkpqOjgAXjgKBGwAawAeDtJyKhpaABo+SWk5FF4APnKAek32OAA9BSA)

Comment: I was hoping to put RHS as some variable for new interface created. Like 
`interface WithTooltips { 
  placement: PlacementStrings,
  buttonCount: number
}`
Instead, this way also works

`type CustomTooltipProps = Pick<TooltipProps, "placement">;
interface ExploreButtonProps extends CustomTooltipProps{ buttonCount: number }`

Comment: @RahulKahale In that case, then you can access the type of the property by doing `Type["property"]`. Here's a playground link https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgFQggBsYEwAFKCMAZzgG8BYAKDjnSIC44AiAI0xReAblbswxHMAC2wFAH4eAHzgByfhBgwIMgLTyAJmriqNWnftowhME2c3bd99cWDoYBpMdOv3n61sXNTcPYKgEAHMAC08jcKjYvUDYBJi7XzUdMC8fM2zkm1TM7LUxFgBfVmqWZFQMaTgAUXBiaGAAIQBXJyQqGnpmNnY4fh6dJABhCC6UHiQumX40cpG4SWk5OYIiUnJ+ugBtXg3cLZheAF0ROAB6W7hsTCQ4TGJaCDhDT4ADFuxiF1DMAADyEEhkSjUI4nKRneQXS4AGjgs2B6GQwEMAD4foh0HAAJ4zL4QJBZOAAd2e8DR7kxhlYFSAA

Comment: Perfect! Thanks 